# if image is exists by the link return true else false

Tags: javascript, image

I have a code. It is verifying existing of the image. It works perfectly if instead of "return true;" I set "alert("exists");".

With "return true;" it return "undefined";
Why code do not work with "return true;"?

I exetute code like this `gallery.VerifyImg("https://jonarhipov.neocities.org/2.png");`

```
var gallery = {
    items: [],
    ItemsConstructor: function ItemsConstructor(img_url) {
        this.img_url = img_url;
    },
    CreateItem: function LoadImage(i) {
        /*
        gallery.items[i] = new ItemsConstructor("https://jonarhipov.neocities.org/" + i + ".jpg");
        $(".gallery").append("<div class='item' style='background-image: url(" + gallery.items[i].img_url + ")'></div>");*/
    },
    VerifyImg: function VerifyImg(url) {
        var success;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function(){return true;};
        img.onerror = function(){return false;};

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a callback function instead of promises

```
    var gallery = {
    items: [],
    ItemsConstructor: function ItemsConstructor(img_url) {
        this.img_url = img_url;
    },
    CreateItem: function LoadImage(i) {
        /*
        gallery.items[i] = new ItemsConstructor("https://jonarhipov.neocities.org/" + i + ".jpg");
        $(".gallery").append("<div class='item' style='background-image: url(" + gallery.items[i].img_url + ")'></div>");*/
    },
    VerifyImg: function VerifyImg(url,cb) {
        var success;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = cb;
        img.onerror = cb;

    }
}
```

Invoke it like so

```
gallery.VerifyImg(url,function(response) {
  console.log(response.type) //returns load or error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VerifyImg: function VerifyImg(url) {
        var success;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function(){return true;};
        img.onerror = function(){return false;};

    }
```

`return true;` in this case returns from inner function, `img.onload` handler, that's why `VerifyImg` returns `undefined`. You should do something like this (sync solution):

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', url, false);
http.send();

return http.status >= 200 && http.status < 400;
```

If you want modern async solution, you can use `fetch` function:

```
return fetch(url, {method: "HEAD"}).then(data => data.status >= 200 && data.status < 400);
```

Both this versions of code won't download whole image from server, they will check if it's exists using `HEAD` request, that's faster and saves traffic.

Comment: thanks! It is long to learning it for me

Answer (score 0):

Your method is almost correct, you just need to return the Promise as image loading is async:

```
VerifyImg: function VerifyImg(url) {
    var promise = new Promise();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = promise.resolve;
    img.onerror = promise.reject;
    return promise;

}
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working

Comment: Probably you are using it in a wrong way. `VerifyImage(url).then(() => console.log('exists')).catch(() => console.log('not exists'))`